# Trim all characters in a field after a certain character

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a column titled email. Obviously this is a list of emails. where someone has 2 emails in their record, the database separates them by ' ' (space).

I need to deleted everything from the space (including the space)

I've tried 
UPDATE employee SET email = TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM email);

which I found in heaps of other posts but it does nothing!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

it should be something like:

```
update employee set email = substring_index(email, ' ', 1)
```